# EF 5. Intersection performance

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am using Entity Framework 5 and I have the entities: Users, Roles and Files.

I need to check if two list of roles have at least one item in common:

```
List<Role> a = user.Roles;
List<Role> b = file.Roles;

Boolean commonRoleFound = a.Intersect(b).Count() > 0;
```

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe using ANY? Maybe other?

What would be the option with better performance?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 1):

In theory "Any" would be faster because you don't need to know how many, just that at least one intersects.  It could stop comparing after it found the record that was in both lists.